# Create dynamic table with multi dimensional array data?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello experts I am new in laravel and php. I have an multi dimensional array and with this array data I want to create a dynamic table and its maximum count will be 10 as a newbie I can't reach to the perfect result. My array as bellow:

> array:4 [▼
>    0 => array:2 [▼
>       0 => {#404 ▼
>         +"id": 290
>         +"amount": "8500.00"
>       }
>       1 => {#403 ▼
>         +"id": 399
>         +"amount": "8500.00"
>       }
>    ]
>    1 => array:4 [▼
>       0 => {#402 ▼
>         +"id": 107
>         +"amount": "6590.00"
>       }
>       1 => {#401 ▼
>         +"id": 355
>         +"amount": "6590.00"
>       }
>       2 => {#400 ▼
>         +"id": 698
>         +"amount": "6590.00"
>       }
>       3 => {#399 ▼
>         +"id": 734
>         +"amount": "6590.00"
>       }
>    ]
>    2 => array:1 [▼
>       0 => {#108 ▼
>         +"id": 21
>         +"amount": "3240.00"
>       }
>    ]
>    3 => array:2 [▼
>       0 => {#397 ▼
>         +"id": 27
>         +"amount": "3030.00"
>       }
>       1 => {#396 ▼
>         +"id": 50
>         +"amount": "3030.00"
>       }
>    ]
>  ]

And With this array I want to create a table like as bellow:

> Serial               ID       
>   Amount 
>  1         290      
>     8500
>  1         399    
>       8500
>
> 2         107        
>   6590
>  2         355      
>     6590
>  2         698    
>       6590
>  2         734  
>         6590
>
> 3         108        
>   3240
>
> 4         27         3030
>   4         50         3030

And I am trying with this in laravel :

```
   $flag = 0;

   $tableDesign = '';

  for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  $tableDesign .="<tr><td>".$flag++."</td><td>".$data[$i][0]."</td>  <td>".$data[$i][1]."</td></tr>";
  if($flag == 10)
  { return;}

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your array before displaying in the table like this:

```
$newData = array();
$flag = 1;
foreach($data as $key => $elements) {

    if($flag > 10) {
        break;
    }

    foreach($elements as $element) {

        $newDataElement = array(
            'serial' => $key + 1,
            'id' => $element['id'],
            'amount' => $element['amount']
        );

        array_push($newData, $newDataElement);
    }

    $flag++;
}
```

Then you can display it simply:

```
<?php foreach($newData as $element): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php print $element['serial']?></td>
    <td><?php print $element['id']?></td>
    <td><?php print $element['amount']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @aeonsleo here is a problem with serial. You just take only top ten but with all similar data will be count as one such ( 1(se)         290(id)         8500(amount) 
1(se)         399(id)         8500(amount)

Comment: Taken out the $flag++ to the outer foreach loop. Hope that solves.

Comment: Thank you very much Aeonsleo. It works but still a problem with serial. May be I can't express my problem clearly.  Same amount will be in same serial number.

Comment: I don't see any issue, same amount should be in same serial no. The output should be the same as you pointed in the table above.